# what is the right whl file for pyqt4 for heroku deployment

Tags: python, heroku, pyqt4

.whl file for pyqt4 mentioned in the requirements.txt fails to install

I am new to both Flask and Heroku.
I tried making a flask app ,it uses pyqt4 for webview.
I want the app to be deployed in heroku.
pyqt4 is removed from pip as pip now has pyqt5,for some reasons i could not get the code running with pyqt5,so I included the url of the pyqt4 .whl in the requirements.txt. Running the command  git push heroku master gives the message:

```
remote:        PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

The flask app runs locally with the installed pyqt4 without any errors,so i think there is no problem with the file

folder structure:
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WVYp.png)

requirements.txt:-

```
aniso8601==7.0.0
appdirs==1.4.3
autopep8==1.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cssselect==1.0.3
docutils==0.14
fake-useragent==0.1.11
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.13.2
Jinja2==2.10.1
lxml==4.3.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
parse==1.12.0
parso==0.3.4
pluggy==0.8.1
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pydocstyle==3.0.0
pyee==6.0.0
pyflakes==2.1.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pypiwin32==223
pyppeteer==0.0.25
PyQt5-sip==4.19.17
pyquery==1.4.0
python-jsonrpc-server==0.1.2
python-language-server==0.23.2
pytz==2019.1
pywin32==224
requests==2.21.0
requests-html==0.10.0
rope==0.12.0
sip==4.19.8
six==1.12.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
soupsieve==1.9.1
tqdm==4.32.1
urllib3==1.24.1
w3lib==1.20.0
websockets==7.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
yapf==0.26.0
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/t4jqbe6o/PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Am i doing anything wrong,if yes then what is the right way to include .whl files in requirements.txt?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem: `PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. This wheel can only be used on 32bit windows systems. If you are running on a different system, you'd have to use a different wheel.

Comment: i tried using all the different wheel files,but the problem persists

Comment: What OS are you running on? And is it 32 or 64?

Comment: windows 10 64 bit but python is 32 bit version

Comment: Is that regarding the heroku environment?

Comment: Yes, I gave up on it and used requests module.,anyways thanks